# T-SQL validation for dates in a loop?

Tags: sql-server

I an working with financial time series. I have a user defined function that tells me the previous available trading date for some security. I am now trying to wrtie a user defined function that will compute volatility, to do this, I need to check that there is data for the previous n trading days.

My date function returns Null if there is no previous trading day. What is a good way to check for the `n` previous trading days? Suppose the function is called `previous` and takes as parameters the security `id` and `date` (and it then checks if there is trading date prior to this date).

I would need to run some sort of a loop?

Comment: It is easy to do with a [Calendar](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) table or more generic table of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you tweak the following

```
Declare @KeyDate Date ='2015-12-31'
Declare @Days    int  = 15
Declare @Ticker  varchar(25) = 'AAPL'

;with cteBase as (
    Select *
          ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Order By Date Desc)
     From  [Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Ticker_History] 
     Where Ticker=@Ticker
       and Date<=@KeyDate
)
Select * from cteBase where RowNr<=@Days
```

Returns

[image]